# Multiple Submit buttons suddenly stop posting to controller in IE on server

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a few submit buttons in my view and noticed that after adding another submit button, the multiple submit buttons have stopped posting to controller. I can not find an error message which would point me in the right direction.

The submit button with the value create works fine, its the submit buttons with the value of "Upload" and "Upload Buffer" have stopped working.  They seem to not hit the controller action at all.  Everything works fine in Firefox and even Safari.  The only new thing I remember adding was the date-time picker controller with slider access.  Could that possibly affect the submit buttons?

**View**

```
@model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntry
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/runLogEntry.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Enter a new Run Log Entry</legend>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div id="main">
            @Html.Partial("_RunLogEntryPartialView", Model)
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/exitCode.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntry
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/runDates.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/errorCode.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/testexception.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/datetime.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    var runDatesUrl = '@Url.Action("LogFileConfirmation", "RunLogEntry")';
    var runlogListErrorsUrl = '@Url.Action("ListErrorCodes", "RunLogEntry")';

    function displayDate(e) {
        $('#runDatestreeview :checked').removeAttr('checked');
    }

</script>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="exception">@(ViewBag.ErrorMessage)</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">Load List File (Select): </span><span class="rightContent">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file1" style="width: 500px" />
    </span>
</div>
@if (Model.LoadListStoredFileName != null)
{
    <div class="bodyContent">
        <span class="leftContent">Attached Load List: </span><span class="rightContent">
            @Html.ActionLink(Model.LoadListFileName, "Download", new { @file = Model.LoadListStoredFileName })
        </span>
    </div>
}
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">Output File (Select): </span><span class="rightContent">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file2" style="width: 500px" />
    </span>
</div>
@if (Model.OutputStoredFileName != null)
{
    <div class="bodyContent">
        <span class="leftContent">Attached Output: </span><span class="rightContent">
            @Html.ActionLink(Model.OutputFileName, "Download", new { @file = Model.OutputStoredFileName })
        </span>
    </div>
}
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">Log/Zip File: </span><span class="rightContent">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file3" style="width: 500px" />
    </span>
</div>
@if (Model.AttachedLogFileName != null)
{
    <div class="bodyContent">
        <span class="leftContent">Attached Log File(s): </span><span class="rightContent">
            @Html.ActionLink(Model.LogFileName, "Download", new { @file = Model.LogFileStoredName })
        </span>
    </div>
}
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">Import Files: </span>
    <button type="submit" id="btn_uploadbuffer" name="submit" value="UploadBuffer" class="art-button"
        style="width: 100px">
        Upload Buffer</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btn_upload" name="submit" value="Upload" class="art-button"
        style="width: 100px">
        Upload Normal</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btn_remove" name="submit" value="Remove" class="art-button"
        style="width: 100px">
        Remove Files</button>
</div>
@*<input name="inputName" type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" value="x" />*@
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Operator")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.DropDownList("OperatorID", String.Empty)
    </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Run ID")
    </span><span class="rightContent">[Generated] </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Run Start Date / Time")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RunDate)
    </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("System")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.DropDownList("SystemID", String.Empty)
    </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Run Type")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.DropDownList("RunTypeID", String.Empty)
    </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Run Description")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.RunDescription, new { style = "width: 600px; height=30px" })
    </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Assay Performance Issues")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.DropDownList("AssayPerformanceIssues1", ListHelpers.YesNoList())
    </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Tests/Cycles Requested")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SPTestsRequested)
    </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Tests/Cycles Completed")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SPTestsCompleted)
    </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Run Status")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.DropDownList("RunStatusID", String.Empty)
    </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Assay")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedAssayIDs, new MultiSelectList(RunLog.Domain.Lists.GlobalList.AssayListItems(), "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedAssayIDs))
    </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    @if (Model.RunDatesDisplay != null && Model.RunDatesDisplay.Count() > 0)
    {
        <span class="leftContent">
            @Html.Label("Run Dates")
        </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="RunDatesChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">
            Click here to Select/View Run Dates</span>
            <br />
            <span id="RunDatesDisplayy" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">
            </span></span>
    }
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Error Code")
    </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="ChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">Click
        here to Select Error Codes</span>
        <br />
        <span id="ErrorCodeDisplay" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">@(Model.ErrorDescription)</span>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ErrorDescription)
    </span>
</div>
<div id="treeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
    overflow: scroll; width: 800px; height: 450px; display: none;">
    <div id="errorCodes">
        @*  @Html.RenderTree(CacheHelper.ErrorCodes(), ec => ec.Name, ec => ec.Children.ToList(), ec => (ec.ID).ToString(), null, "e")*@
        @Html.RenderTree(CacheHelper.ErrorCodes(), ec => ec.Name, ec => ec.Children.ToList(), ec => (ec.ID).ToString(), Model.ErrorCodes, "error")
    </div>
    <div id="inputReps" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    @if (Model.TestExceptionDisplay != null && Model.TestExceptionDisplay.Count() > 0)
    {
        <span class="leftContent">
            @Html.Label("Test Exceptions")
        </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="TestExceptionChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">
            Click here to View Test Exceptions</span>
            <br />
            <span id="TestExceptionDisplayy"></span></span>
    }
</div>
<div id="testExceptiontreeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
    overflow: scroll; width: 800px; height: 450px; display: none;">
    <table class="grid" style="width: 600px; margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Exception
                </th>
                <th>
                    Frequency
                </th>
                <th>
                    Comment
                </th>
                <th>
                    Replicate Range
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.TestExceptionDisplay != null)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TestExceptionDisplay)
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="runDatestreeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
    overflow: scroll; width: 400px; height: 450px; display: none;">
    <table class="grid" style="width: 600px; margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Run Dates
                </th>
                <th>
                    Frequency
                </th>
                <th>
                    Min Replicate
                </th>
                <th>
                    Max Replicate
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RunDatesDisplay)
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Service Entry Request")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.DropDownList("ServiceRequest", ListHelpers.YesNoList())
    </span>
</div>
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Problem Description")
    </span><span class="rightContent">
        @Html.TextArea("ProblemDescription", new { style = "width: 600px; height: 30px" })
    </span>
</div>
@if (Model.UserRole == "Admin" || Model.UserRole == "SuperUser")
{
    <div class="bodyContent">
        <span class="leftContent">
            @Html.Label("Active")
        </span><span class="rightContent">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active)
        </span>
    </div>
}
else
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Active)
}
<p>
    <input id="LogType" type="hidden" value="Run" />
    <input id="ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
    @if (Model.ExitCode == "1")
    {
        @Html.Hidden("ExitCode", Model.ExitCode)
    }
    else
    {
        <input id="ExitCode" type="hidden" value='0' />
    }
    @if (Model.LogFileModal == "1")
    {
        <input id="LogModals" type="hidden" value='0' />
    }
    else
    {
        <input id="LogModal" type="hidden" value='1' />
    }
</p>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MaxReplicateId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MinReplicateId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OutputFileName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OutputStoredFileName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LoadListFileName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LoadListStoredFileName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LogFileName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LogFileStoredName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AttachedLogFileName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AttachedMultipleLogFileNames)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MinTestCompletionDate)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MaxTestCompletionDate)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RunLogMode)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserRole)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Active)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ParseType)
<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent"></span><span class="rightContent">
        <button id="btn_create" name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Create">
            Create</button></span>
</div>
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(RunLogEntry runLogEntry, String ServiceRequest, string Hour, string Minute, string AMPM,
                                 string submit, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file, String AssayPerformanceIssues1, List<string> Replicates)
    {
```